# Re-Architecting C++ Application with Unit Testing in Mind

Tags: c++, unit-testing, architecture

I am starting to think about re-architecting a large C++ application with unit testing in mind.  Most of the reading that I have done has lead me to mock frameworks (i.e. google mock).  However, one of my design goals is to keep the software as simple as possible for easy maintainability.

My issue is that it seems like you need to add considerable complexity to the application in order to build in the dependency injection that is required to use mock classes.

For example, you would need to add abstract base classes for all classes that could need to be mocked so that you can instantiate "production" objects in the production code and "mock" objects in the unit test code.  This is somewhat undesirable because of the number of extra classes and the added level of abstraction to all classes.  Also, do you add an abstract base class defining the public interface to EVERY class?  If you don't, how could you be sure that the class will never need to be mocked?

Or, you need to templatize all of your classes so you can "inject" mock objects in the unit testing code.  I definitely do not want an application where every class is a template class.

What has everyone's experience been with this?  How have you built testability into your architecture and what has the outcome been?

Comment: My related language agnostic advice, since you're re-architecting, is to remove these complex dependancies. Eg. If I had a (untestable) class that did complex things to data using the database, I might split that to a (easily testable) class that did complex things to objects and a simple/boring class that knows about the database and orchestrates the interesting one (less testable but dull). ... I stilll think mocks are cool, but they can be a bit of a crutch.

Answer (score 3):

> For example, you would need to add abstract base classes for all
>   classes that could need to be mocked so that you can instantiate
>   "production" objects in the production code and "mock" objects in the
>   unit test code. This is somewhat undesirable because of the number of
>   extra classes and the added level of abstraction to all classes.

I think first you have to appreciate the need for this before a mock-based testing framework makes a lot of sense.

For example, in my case, I've worked on a lot of somewhat-large codebases. They're not gigantic with the smallest being about half a million lines of code, largest being about 20 million LOC. Yet even the smallest one here benefited a great deal from having abstract interfaces at the heart of the software's design.

***Abstract Central Interfaces***

One of the things that all of these codebases had in common was a software development kit at the heart of their foundations. Third parties would write and sometimes even sell plugins for our products using our SDK, and they built those plugins using the same central APIs we used to build the main products.

To be able to write a plugin that is added at runtime requires that the plugin depends on abstract interfaces with the concrete implementations being somewhere else (ex: in the main application binary or in another plugin).

So in our case, there was a strong need for the heart of the software to consist of abstract interfaces, with or without unit testing in mind*. Every major component in the system was used through an abstract interface, whether it was an image, mesh, particle system, renderer, even UI concepts like widgets and layouts were used abstractly. Even our image loader/saver was abstract so that the software could, with the mere addition of a plugin at runtime (even one written by a third party), come to be able to load and save image formats it formerly could not recognize.

<sub>* In our case, our abstract interfaces were C-like using tables of function pointers for the widest compatibility, but with statically-linked C++ wrappers on top of the most commonly-used interfaces to make them safer and easier to use.</sub>

***Mock Testing Should Make a Natural Fit***

In such a case, a mock testing framework makes a natural fit. You don't have to go out of your way to design things for dependency injection in those cases, it comes naturally. With abstract interfaces making up the foundation of the software that have no access to concrete details, there is no choice but to depend on other abstractions passed in.

> Also, do you add an abstract base class defining the public interface
>   to EVERY class? If you don't, how could you be sure that the class
>   will never need to be mocked?

In line with the above, you shouldn't necessarily make classes depend on abstract interfaces superficially just for the sake of dependency injection and mocking. Otherwise you might find yourself questioning every little design decision like this, and that can turn into a smell. There should be other needs compelling you to make those central, widely-used interfaces abstract independent of mock testing. There should be characteristics driving you to seek abstractions at the heart of the software, provided that it fits the kind of scalability/extensibility requirements that make mock testing a useful strategy.

***Not Every Project Benefits From Mostly-Abstract Interfaces***

For some smaller or very rigidly-defined projects, seeking to make all central interfaces abstract is going to be complete overkill and end up being counter-productive. In those kinds of cases, there isn't quite as strong of a need for a rigidly-defined unit testing procedure. The tests can be a blur between unit testing and integration testing in such cases, and that would be perfectly acceptable in such rigidly-defined, inextensible scopes. Unit testing in these types of abstract cases is most useful in a team setting where you want to test your work in isolation and independently of Joe's work, which could be incorrect or may become incorrect in the future. If you are the sole author and maintainer of the work and in control of everything, typically one of the greatest source of unknowns is plugged, the world is no longer shifting under your feet, and integration testing will typically start to seem increasingly useful while the usefulness of unit testing, and especially in cases that involve mocking, will seem diminished.

***Integration Testing***

Even in codebases where everything depends on abstractions, integration testing can be extremely useful. There are sometimes unfortunate edge cases that only show up when two or more concrete implementations are combined together, where both pass their tests when tested individually but fail when combined.

Typically these show up when there's some kind of intermediary code which both are using with some obscure form of temporal coupling involved, like both of these entities might use some graphics library but the graphics library does something funky based on the order of operations the code under your control requests when combined together.

Yet integration testing is often a pain in large projects since they often need to build a complex structure from real-world inputs. In those cases, a useful trick I've found in C and C++ is to actually run the tests from within plugins, to give dylibs an optional entry point function they can provide which is used solely for testing purposes.

This way the main testing application can still construct the "world" (in our case, a scene graph) used for testing and then load and execute the appropriate test plugin. This makes it so all the code normally required in each integration test to start up the system, construct/load all the necessary data in advance, shut it down, etc. is no longer required in each test plugin. We just set up the world once in a central binary and then load the appropriate test plugin. It also just tends to encourage less brittle tests which are still testing a fairly isolated part even in the integration testing realm. Just by human nature, it seems that when testing of any sort requires a great deal of boilerplate, people want to write monolithic tests (which unfortunately tend to be more brittle).

***Not Everything Should Be Abstract***

There are also typically edge cases even if your project fits the necessary abstraction requirements for mock testing. For example, even in my cases where the bulk of the system was dependent on abstract interfaces provided through an SDK, we had a small portion of interfaces which weren't abstract in the slightest.

A prominent example that comes to mind is our math library which consisted largely of vector/matrix class templates for linear algebra. In those cases, the math library formed a stable root package (zero afferent couplings as Robert C. Martin would describe it through his instability metric): it didn't depend on anything else. So those libraries were easy to unit test in isolation. We'd write tests to make sure that a vector dot product yielded an expected outcome (with expected results being obtained elsewhere which were verified to be correct), e.g.

So stable "roots" of this sort which are already independent of the world are easy to test in isolation even without involving any abstractions. Sometimes C++ templates are useful here as a decoupling mechanism to decouple a class template or function template from the outside world, make it completely independent. Yet again, you shouldn't necessarily force everything to be a class template or function template solely for the purpose of testing. There's a lot more that a generic, standard-compliant sequence container has going for it than testability as an example. Even though testability is definitely a strong plus, it's not the strongest reason to make something generic.

***Don't Force It***

Anyway, so my basic advice is *don't force it*. Don't force everything to be an independent class/function template or an abstract interface solely for the sake of testing. The first and foremost benefit is dynamic or static polymorphism. There should be extensibility and reusability kind of concerns there first and foremost, and then ease of testing follows the decoupled nature of code depending solely on abstract interfaces. Yet it's not necessarily productive to superficially redirect all the dependencies throughout your project towards abstract interfaces solely for testability. Try to find other reasons to make things abstract without just testing in mind (although it is a useful goal).